# What is the huge JSON file in Pycharm at PyCharmCE2022.3\python_packages\packages_v2.json? It takes up 166.5 GB

Tags: pycharm

My PC was getting full so I ran TreeSize, and I found a 166.5 GB large file in the PyCharm files. It is located at C:\Users..\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.3\python_packages\packages_v2.json. I am not even using Community edition anymore, so I am going to delete it, but I wondered if anybody knows what it is and why it is so large. In the same place in my professional PyCharm installation a 7 MB large file is located.

The only explanation I can think of is that I recently downloaded StableDiffusion, so maybe something went wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my pycharm, that is a ~6Mb file. Looking at the content, it seems to be some information about installed packaging. probably from the indexing, but I don't know for sure. For exactly your pycharm version though, there seems to be a number of people reporting a very huge filesize. Presumably some kind of bug, see

[here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8897951104146-PyCharm-packages-v2-json-very-large)

and

[here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57156/Gigantic-file-.cache-JetBrains-CLion2022.3-pythonpackages-packagesv2.json?_gl=1*10gpipo*_ga*Mzg5NjYwMTkuMTY4NTk1MDcxMQ..*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY4NjA1MjkzOS4zLjEuMTY4NjA1MzQyOC42MC4wLjA.&_ga=2.61469801.477387772.1686043301-38966019.1685950711)